# Is WSL 2 secure for commercial work?

Tags: windows, linux, wsl

Windows Subsystem for Linux (version 2) is getting more and more traction lately with new features being added such as GUI mode over Wayland (WSLg). It seems to me Microsoft really pushes for WSL usage, however, I am worried about the underlying security.

I have read several articles which put me into panic mode.

Running Sensitive Apps in WSL: (SAFE + SAFE) < SAFE
https://www.cyberark.com/resources/threat-research-blog/running-sensitive-apps-in-wsl-safe-safe-safe

Whitepaper by F-Secure
https://img.en25.com/Web/FSecure/%7B87c32f0e-962d-4454-b244-1bb8908968d4%7D_WSL-2-RESEARCH.pdf

Some excerpts from the above:

> The loopback attack, for the WSL 2 VM, is a Local Privilege Escalation vulnerability that is explicitly enabled by the “Lightweight Utility VM” features of WSL 2. This vulnerability does not exist if an equivalent Linux system is run in a full VM under Windows.

> The main security risk identified here is credentials theft or theft of other sensitive data processed by Linux applications running inside WSL.

> An additional consideration is the security programs that may be active in the machine. To the best of my knowledge and at the time this blog was published, there is currently no known Windows security program that protects Linux files (inside the WSL file system).

> Any security programs that might be implemented inside the WSL VM (e.g., maybe protecting SSH keys) will not be active while the attack is carried out.

> The use of Hyper-V no doubt improves the efficiency of the system, however its use of “.vhdx” image files makes behavioral and binary analysis almost impossible. This lack of coverage, short of installing an agent on the virtual machine itself, seriously impacts a hunter’s ability to categorize the presence of such a component.

TLDR - WSL is unusable for any kind of work with sensitive data, that is almost any kind of commercial work, and current antivirus programs aren't able to sufficiently defend against these threats.

I'm not a security expert, so I thought I would ask here. Since WSL undergoes a lot of development and the articles are more than a year old, has any of these issues been adressed by Microsoft as of middle 2021?

Seems strange to me they would focus so much on new features and not fix anything this critical. Or is it just me overreacting and this is not really such a big issue? Should I be worried and avoid using WSL 2 for commercial work?

Comment: You'll have to come up with a threat model to get any specific answers. If the threat model is that the host is not trusted, the conclusion is of course that the WSL environment can't be trusted either.

Comment: Furthermore, commercial doesn't mean sensitive. Me developing an application can be commercial - but if it's only used with test data and credentials with minimal access it's not *sensitive* by any stretch.

Comment: It's as secure as Windows for commercial use.

Comment: "commercial work" doesn't really say anything about what risks you are worried about. You say "sensitive data" at one point, and that's better, but you still don't give an indication of the threats you are worried about. If your question is simply about whether those issues you quote have been mitigated, then that's a much easier and more straightforward question to answer.

Comment: My apologies, to give a more specific example: in my case sensitive data would be source code but also ssh keys for gitlab, and most importantly, I am using linux to connect to client environments with aws cli or kubectl and obviously I need to secure credentials. But really, I can be writing word documents or a photos editing in photoshop and these might be sensitive too.

I understand that if Windows host is compromised, WSL is too. But this is not any different from a regular VM. According to the article I linked, in WSL case you can compromise WSL with user process, unlike in regular VM.

Comment: In a comment you make to the answer you say _unable to detect malware in Linux binaries_ and I think that is a critical point that your question does not say.

Answer (score 11):

WSL is as secure as any other program running in your Windows user account. It's not suitable for isolating a Linux VM from your Windows host (in either direction); it is designed to simulate the experience of just running user-mode Linux binaries natively on Windows (which is what WSLv1 does). Don't think of WSL as a VM; while v2 *technically* is one, it is so deeply integrated into the host OS and user session that it's best to assume there's no meaningful security boundary **beyond what already exists between Windows processes**. That bold part is important: if you have malicious software running on your Windows session, *the entire session* including WSLv2 is already compromised. You'll note that all the exploits in the first article either require malicious code running in the Windows session, or in the Linux session.

The main way this confuses people is that WSL has its own Linux-based security model. However, this is completely irrelevant to the actual security of the system. Think of it as a toy, or an advisory thing; it might stop you from making a mistake, but it doesn't actually enforce any actual security controls.

Only the Windows security model matters. Running as root inside WSL doesn't actually give more permissions than running as a standard user; the things that you can do from that perspective are 100% exactly the same (in either case) as the things that the user who ran the Windows `wsl.exe` program (or other WSL-launching command) could do. Similarly, if WSL was launched as Admin, then code running inside it can do approximately everything, even if it's not root as far as Linux is concerned.

Does this make it insecure? Not at all. You just have to remember that everything that runs in the Windows session (whether or not it's also in a Linux session, and regardless of what Linux user it runs as) has the same access. Don't run malicious code. If you need a VM for a sandbox, use one that's configured for isolation, not for seamless integration.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I still have doubts. What if I use firewall and antivirus on Windows host: these will only protect me against Windows-based threats, wouldn’t they? It’s what both articles mention. Indeed, I pay for Avira and texted their support and they confirmed that they are unable to detect malware in Linux binaries, which is what WSL would run. They don’t have a Linux offering, so can’t detect it. So having protection just on the host would leave WSL open to vulnerabilities and if I want to work commercialy in WSL, I not only need to protect the host but the WSL instance too.

Comment: Since non-admin Windows processes have access to WSL data (according to articles above), and they can override anything inside wsl, e.g. replace my awscli or kubectl programs with something that leaks credentials to an attacker, and WSL is able to run non-admin Windows processes without root, it’s precisely this kind of integration that basically allows WSL-aware malware in Linux binaries (ie. untraceable by Windows antivirus) to take control of the WSL instance. Am I wrong here?

Comment: You're not wrong, your threat model just doesn't make any sense. If you start with the assumption that malicious code is already running on your machine, *you have already failed*. WSL isn't a sandbox, and sandboxes are the only place you should make an assumption like that. Also, if you're relying on antivirus for anything, you're making a huge mistake... but for what it's worth, Windows AV software (Defender) can detect Linux "malware" (I've seen it twice, both legit tools I'd intentionally downloaded). If you download the malware within Linux, run your AV there.

Comment: To put it differently, why are you worrying about malicious Windows processes leaking your awscli file from within Linux, when it could just as easily leak anything from within Windows? You're acting like WSL is supposed to be a "normal" Linux VM, with strict isolation from the host OS and its own security controls and so on. This is all, explicitly, plainly, false. WSL is Wine-in-reverse, and the fact that WSLv2 is *technically* a VM doesn't change the fact that its security model is "all these processes are running within your Windows login session". Don't run malicious software there!

Comment: Ok, I obviously don't want to run malicious software anywhere. I'm worried this might happen by accident, there is no such thing as 100% protection and even if I follow all the best practices, I might slip on a bad day. My AV knowledge here might be lacking but I'm more worried about Windows proccesses leaking WSL data than Windows proccesses leaking host-only data because according to the articles (and at least Avira too), malicious actions in Windows are more readable by my current protection mechanisms (AV), whereas Linux binaries are pretty much unreadable and therefore would be undetected

Comment: They would appear as random data to AV, according to my understaning. I'm just trying to evaluate risk here and ways to mitigate it. Windows Defender being able to detect Linux malware would be the first AV I've heard about with this ability. Could you recommend any other ways to mitigate this risk? Or did you want to say by all of the above that this is something I should not worry about?

Comment: @CBHacking Isn't it safe to assume that without any AV installed into the WSL2 instance, malware downloaded into WSL2 will stay undetected and possible act on behalf of the WSL2 user to attack Windows?

Comment: @Shuzheng Yes, same as with any VM that has integration features enabled (I'd give better odds of detection with WSLv1, where the downloaded file is being written to the same file system and through the same kernel as the AV). On the other hand, it is *unsafe* to assume that any AV will ever detect anything, so your security protections should already be built around the "AV won't help" scenario. Run a (Linux) AV inside WSL if you want the vary dubious protection of AV in all environments, just like you must with all VMs (if you care about comprehensive AV coverage).

Comment: In my situation my Visual Studio builds (the exe files built from my code) were asking for permissions they did not need and did not ask for in the past. Kaspersky insisted my system was clean and advised me to allow all the permissions they asked for. Since Kaspersky does not look at WSL 2 programs, I am convinced there was something in there trying to inject code into my builds. (I will not renew my Kaspersky license.)

Comment: @SamHobbs The odds that you managed to pick up WSL 2 malware that specifically targets developers using Visual Studio (rather than doing their dev work in WSL) is... look, I'm not saying that it _couldn't_ happen, but it's so extremely unlikely that I really can't imagine why anybody would bother. You understand that such malware could just take over your entire Windows account, right? Why would it bother with merely tampering with the (very visible) requested permissions on a compiled app? That makes no sense. I refer you to https://xkcd.com/1180/

Comment: @SamHobbs Also, just checking, did you try disabling WSL (or at least shutting off all instances) and compiling your source code again, or compiling on a machine that has never used WSL at all? For that matter, did you crack the compiled app open to read its manifest and see what permissions it was requesting there? It's entirely possible that the new user-visible requests are simply due to an OS update, or a third-party library update. If it somehow is malware, though, it should be possible to get a different result on a clean install on a different machine.

Comment: @CBHacking I did disable WSL and virtualization and everything such as that; that did not help. So somehow my Windows was infected yet Kaspersky insisted it is not. I now have a new system. I intend to clean out previous builds and rebuild the applications in this new system but I have not yet done much of that. I think permissions are not relevant to my desktop applications. I know that the source code does nothing that requires special permissions.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated answer:**

In a word:  yes and no.

---

Why?

1. It can be made more secure to an extent by running as a different user, although this requires some tricky maneuvering..

- AccountA is administrator-level
- Login to AccountA
- Create AccountB as Administrator also
- Logout of AccountA
- Login as AccountB
- Set up the distro on accountB (wsl install -d Ubuntu)
- logout of AccountB
- login to AccountA
- Change AccountB to Standard User
- Open WSL as AccountB  (runas /USER:accountB bash)

As long as Account B cannot bypass traverse checking, or login as another user who can, then WSL is now sandboxed into a Standard User.

You can now do things like host a web server without exposing AccountA's files and/or permissions to WSL, essentially locking it into its own namespace.

There is one small issue however. Performance. Routing WSL through RUNAS is extremely slow compared to running it as the current user.

There are also some graphical issues that can arise from this setup and may require special configuration.

Other than that, it could potentially be used in a production environment if one were so inclined.

---

Then why no?

Because this setup  is a major workaround and is not something you could just embed into an EXE and be able to run Linux programs without having to jump through hoops. So, I would consider it not commercial ready. Also, there is no real isolated context in that you can't have a Linux environment that is 100% isolated -- I.E. any program with Windows level access can just do bash -c "rm -rf *" and wipe out your home directory without even logging in.